# Задание Content-Type в html

Tags: html, content-type

Где в html указывается Content-Type (помниться, что в теге `meta`, но не помню точно как задается синтаксически)? Искал [content-type html](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf=ALeKk010KjbtV3WJRegJbtHeBb6tt9NuYQ%3A1602487667109&ei=cwWEX5qaBqiHrwTjzIqoDw&q=content-type%20html&oq=content-type%20htm&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgcIABAUEIcCMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgIIADIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB46BAgAEEc6BAgjECc6BAgAEENQgfYDWPaGBGCvmwRoAHACeACAAfUBiAG1BJIBBTEuMi4xmAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesgBCMABAQ&sclient=psy-ab), но нашел информацию только по значениям типа.

Comment: Видимо, не в `html`, а в `http`...

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, в html уже поздно говорить, что это html, потому что чтобы браузер стал парсить html и разбирать в нём meta-теги, он должен уже знать, что это именно html.

Мета тег с content-type использовался чтобы переопределить кодировку html-страницы, но он получил более короткий вариант `<meta charset="utf-8">`, который (из-за кривых рук разработчиков сайтов) поддерживался браузерами гораздо раньше, чем стал стандартом.

Так что прописывай нормально в http-заголовках сервера, а не в html.

PS: А искать надо было `meta content-type`:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

Заголовок-сущность Content-Type используется для того, чтобы определить MIME тип ресурса.
В ответах сервера заголовок Content-Type сообщает клиенту, какой будет тип передаваемого контента.
В верстке вы можете задать Content-type только для форм, что бы указать в каком формате данные уйдут на сервер.

В POST запросе, сгенерированном в результате отправки HTML формы, Content-Type запроса определяется в атрибуте enctype тега .

```
<form action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="description" value="some text">
  <input type="file" name="myFile">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```